# Which Azure region is "North Central US"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-regions

I am trying to whitelist an Azure region in an app.  I downloaded the IPs for the regions from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653 and I do not see one that is obviously **North Central US**

For US, there are (in the order they appear in the download):

- uscentraleuap
- uscentral
- useast2euap
- useast2
- useast
- usnorth
- ussouth
- uswestcentral
- uswest2
- uswest

Any idea which is which?  I assume either **uscentral** or **usnorth**?  Some are named very descriptively, others are not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

North and South are both central. Where there are variants (like uswest, uswest2, uswestcentral) it’s because multiple data centres are present. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/global-infrastructure/regions/

You could also use this blog post about the release of that document to correlate with the IP addresses you’re seeing, as the more explicit names are used. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/keithmayer/2013/08/14/windows-azure-datacenter-ip-ranges/